# VBScript RegEx not matching

Tags: regex, vbscript

I'm slightly confused as to how RegExp works. I'm very happy using it to search for strings using something like notepad++, however I'm now trying to search through a string in VBScript and the RegExps that work in notepad++ don't seem compatible with VBScript. I incorrectly presumed that regexp was a standard of sorts. Anyway.

The string I'm trying to search through is:
`"kcabllaCsrevirD - ) 0x0 = TLUSERH ( 'FNI.TRWTS\049BE47424A6-2898-65A4-3538-602212F0\#\$1#40C0010B$gkPrevirD_O_\10RPAFJUOS\\' egakcaP revirD     8202=DI`

I'm trying to identify:
`FNI.TRWTS\`

Using notepad++, and trying to follow the sytax as described in [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms974570.aspx) I've come up with:
`.*?fni\..*?\\`

Can anyone point me in the right direction here? I have other regexps working in VB so am fairly happy that my VB is OK.

For some background on the string - I've reversed a line of text from a DISM log and am trying to extract the driver name, so looking to pick out `fni.*` and then reverse it back to `*.inf`. The reason I'm doing it this way is whilst I can get regexps to search non greedy (`.*?`) I can't seem to find a method of matching last first.

```
Set objFso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set TxtDismLog = objFSO.GetFile("C:\Windows\SysWow64\CCM\Logs\dism.log").OpenAsTextStream(1,-2) 
Set TxtDriverOutput = objFSO.CreateTextFile("C:\Program Files\Sam\drivers.log", 8, True)
Set objRegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
Set objRegEx2 = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")

objRegEx.Global = True   
objRegEx.IgnoreCase = True
objRegEx.Pattern = "Found \d driver package"

objRegEx2.Global = True   
objRegEx2.IgnoreCase = True
objRegEx2.Pattern = "\bfni\.[^\\]*\\"

txtDriverOutput.WriteLine Now() & Chr(32) & "Begin DISM Driver Scan"
Do While TxtDismLog.AtEndOfStream <> True 
txtline = txtDismLog.ReadLine
If objRegEx.Test(txtline) Then
h = InStr(txtline,"Found")
i = Mid(txtline,h+6,1)
Do While i <> 0
i = i - 1
txtline = txtDismLog.ReadLine
txtlinebwd = StrReverse(txtline)
regfindbwd = objRegEx2.Execute(txtlinebwd)
regfind = StrReverse(regfindbwd)
txtDriverOutput.WriteLine regfind
Loop
End If
Loop
```

Comment: What is known in the string? `fni.`? BTW, which tag is correct: vb.net or vbscript? Please show your code.

Comment: Just use fni\..*?\\ with the ignore case flag.

Comment: I don't think I can use fni\..*?\\ , as further through the string the value may reoccur. I'll add the full code now

Comment: Have a look at [``fni\.[^\\]*\\``](https://regex101.com/r/xN2uC3/1). If you use it with a case-insensitive flag, it should work even when multiple values appear in the same string (Global = True with your RegExp is OK then). I will post it.

Comment: There is no difference between fni\..*?\\ and fni\.[^\\]*\\. And @SamH just match the first one. If you're worried about being embedded, just use a whitespace boundary before it, ie (?<!\S)fni\..*?\\ or just a word boundary \b

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that Notepad++ uses Boost regex library which is very powerful, and VBScript uses a very old regex library similar to what JavaScript supports (it is very limited compared to Boost). However, very basic patterns will work the same.

To match a substring starting with `fni.` and ending with `\`, you can use

```
\bfni\.[^\\]*\\
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fV7oX6/1)

The `\b` forces `fni` to be a whole word. `[^\\]` matches any character but a `\`, `*` matches zero or more occurrences, and `\\` matches one `\`.

The `RegExp.Execute` returns *all* matches if you set `objRegEx2.Global = True`, so there is no point setting a loop.

Comment: Does it work now? Without `dism.log` file I do not know how to help more.

Comment: Yes this query now works. Ontop of the Regex issue I had, I was also accidentally using the test method instead of execute - which certainly wasn't helping.